# Need Help in interpretation of results for random forest model

Tags: random-forest, interpretation

I was working on a binary classification problem where the ratio of Y(Unprofitable)/N(Profitable) is 52/148, in a train set with a sample size of 200.

I got expected results with random forest model but I need help to interpret its result

```
predTest<-predict(fit_rf,newdata=combiTest)

confusionMatrix(predTest,combiTest$Unprofitable,positive="Y")
```

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

```
          Reference
Prediction   N     Y
         N   144   39
         Y    6    11
      
                 Accuracy : 0.775           
                   95% CI : (0.7108, 0.8309)
      No Information Rate : 0.75            
    **P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.2332**          
                                          
                  Kappa : 0.2308          
                                          
 **Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.84e-06**        
                                          
            Sensitivity : 0.2200          
            Specificity : 0.9600          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.6471          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.7869          
             Prevalence : 0.2500          
         Detection Rate : 0.0550          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.0850          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.5900          
                                          
       'Positive' Class : Y
```

And:

```
#ExpectedProfitPerAppl= ((4000*(144-6))-(4900*39))/200
#ExpectedProfitPerAppl 1804.5
```

Here P Value[ACC>NIR] = 0.2308 which casts doubt on the fitness of the model but then what is Mcnemar's Test P-Value? I don't have any further validation/production data to test on. The business objective is to have a profitper Appln > base profit(i.e with no model).

Comment: you got it right: the forest is quite bad (it may be better than nothing though). at least try some other method

Comment: What does McNemar test have to do here? You are not comparing two models, so I am a bit confused on how you would like to use it... Can you expand?